# Android : SimpleAdapter with images

Tags: android, android-listview, android-imageview

I have a list view.

each item has an imageview

currently I'm using SimpleAdapter but I can't set the image Bitmap.

I'm using two Array lists one for Bitmaps and one for texts. I'm currently using the texts array list with a simple adapter

Now I wan't to set the downloaded bitmaps for every item in the list. how can I do it ?

I must write an adapter or I can do this without writing adapters ?

Comment: read the documentation for the class you are using. in SimpleAdapter, there is a ViewBinder nested class that is a class you can extend to suite your needs. Also, you'll find SimpleAdapter already supports ImageViews if your content is a Uri (content:// or file://)

Comment: (bottom line to my comment is, the easiest way is to pass the Uri of your file to your adapter, and SimpleAdapter does everything itself)

Answer (score 2):

you need to override `getView` , inflate a custom layout for the `ListView`'s row, with an ImageView and TextView for instance, arranged the way you like, and set text and image on those.

Answer (score 1):

You will indeed have to write your own custom adapter. Inside `getView()`, you will be able to instantiate your own layout xml containing an `ImageView` and a `TextView` which you can fill with your data.

This will get you started: http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html